# How to change the look of JavaFX AreaChart

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I currently have some working JavaFX code which produces an Areachart with 2 number axes. The x-axis is scrollable, so that the window of view can be changed. To increase the user experience, I need to change the look of the chart to below (in green) so that the view is more of a bar chart:

[image: old and new peaks]

My question is, what's the best way of changing the shape of how the areachart is rendered? I've been trawling through the classes than `AreaChart` inherits, but can't seem to work out how the shape of the chart is being rendered.

I've considered interpolating the points (e.g 1 point with value x=10,y=16 becomes 10 points x=9.5->10.4,y=16) but that seems like a lot of computation.

Comment: Why not just use a `BarChart`?

Comment: It doesn't render with 2 `NumberAxis`. One has to be a `CategoryAxis`

Comment: If that's the only issue, it shouldn't be difficult to create a `CategoryAxis` and use the string representation of the values you need for the data. (I agree that generally the chart API is too restrictive on the types you are forced to use for the data.)